# What is the maximum power for an 8-pin PC PSU cable?

Tags: power-supply, atx

I have a non-modular 600W PC PSU which has one 8-wire (3 yellow, 5 black) cable split and connected to two 6+2 connectors (see the image below). I've read that according to the ATX standard, an 8 pin is restricted to 150W. So what maximum power can the two 6+2 connectors transfer together within the standard? 150W or 300W?

[image]

Comment: The title says 8-pin PSU cable, implying 8-pin CPU power connector but the text says 6+2 connector, implying PCI express power connector. Could you clarify?

Comment: I smell similar issues to USB officially supporting 500mA current, yet 2A being a fairly standard charger current. Not sure about rating of the connectors, or the split, but could you estimate the rating from copper area of the cables themselves?

Comment: @Unimportant, Yes, it's for PIC-e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only source for more or less authoritative information is your PSU specs. As far as I can tell, it doesn't specify it, so fhe usual assumption is that if it fits, plug it.

On the other hand, these 550W on the 12V rail should be somehow distributed between 12V outputs and there is no much of them.

A reasonable design would back the split cable with tick enough wires to compensate for the double load. 300W at 12V are ~25A distributed between the 3 yellow wires, so ~8.3A per wire. Not much of an issue if the wire is at least 18AWG or 0.85mm2.

The wire is probably labeled with its gauge, temperature range, manufacturer name and other useful information, so you can see yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Single 6-pin connector allows 75W power delivery, and single 8-pin connector allows 150W power delivery.

Since you need to power two 150W connectors it can draw up to 300W.

If you have split a single 8-pin 150W connector into two 8-pin connectors, it means that there can be double the expected load, so there can be double the expected current in the wiring and voltage at the connectors can be less than expected. Wiring meant to power a single 150W load may not be enough to power a 300W load.

Since the wiring which comes out of the power supply is factory-made with two 8-pin connectors that are 6-pin compatible, there is no doubt that it can handle two 150W loads or 300W in total.

Comment: I haven't split the 8-pin connector. What I meant is that a cable consisting of 8 wires comes out from the PSU and is connected to two 6+2 connectors (designed by the manufacturer itself).

Comment: @apadana Sounds like something a cheap PSU manufacturer would do. What make/model is it? If it's some no-name model then chances are it can't deliver the stated power anyway.

Comment: @Unimportant, It's a ST60F-ES230 made by SilverStone.

Comment: @apadana Splitting wires on a "single-rail" PSU which allows overloading any one cable. (Yes, "single-rail" is a bad thing, not a good thing as many believe). And here I was thinking Silverstone was a quality brand.

Comment: Wait, what? OK so do you mean that there is a single PCIE power cable from the PSU, and it has a detachable 2-pin part, so it is compatible with both 6-pin and 8-pin connectors?

Comment: @Justme, please see the image I just inserted. There are two 6+2 connectors, each with one detachable 2-pin part.

Comment: @apanada And that wiring comes directly out of a power supply? Then each connector can provide 150W, or 300W total. You said it is split so it was misunderstood that wiring for one connector is split into two with a splitter, but this is factory-made.

Answer (score 1):

People sometimes overlook that the GPU has an additional power supply - up to 75W - from the PCIe slot. So, a card with 2 x 8 pin sockets can draw 2 x 150W directly from PSU, plus 75W via PCIe - total 375W.